# Autonum package yields "Output routine didn't use all of \box255." error

Tags: output-routine, autonum

I have been getting an "Output routine didn't use all of \box255." error in all of my documents. I was able to track the problem down to the autonum package. Even in the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

the error occurs. Updating all packages with the MiKTeX console did not help either. What could I possibly do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm unable to replicate the issue you report on my system (MacOS 10.15.7 "Catalina"; MacTeX2020 with all updates applied by `tlmgr` utility; LaTeX2e `<2020-10-01> patch level 2`; article document class `2020/04/10 v1.4m`; and autonum package `2015/01/18 v0.3.11). Please tell us more about your TeX system.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! With recent version of MikTeX I cant reproduce your error. It seems that update your LaTeX installation may help.

Comment: ensure that you update in user and admin mode in the console.

Comment: you probably have an outdated version of the texpos package, but be careful with autonum: it loads `etextools` and so the `etex` package and this is not compatible with everything.

Comment: No issue with an up-to-date TeX Live.